# Unity 2D angular velocity center

Tags: 2d, unity, rotation

I try to add angular velocity to my `GameObject` with this command:

```
rigidbody2D.angularVelocity = Random.value * tumble;
```

All works, but I want center of velocity be in the center of my rigidbody, but center is outside my `GameObject` and looks like every time in different place. How can I set rotation center to the center of my rigidbody?

IMPORTANT: when my GameObject is stay on place (no movement) then all works fine, when I add linear movement it begin rotate around some outside center.

Thanks!

Comment: This seems likely a [Transformation matrix multiplication order](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29260/transform-matrix-multiplication-order) issue. If you apply the rotation first, then the translation, then the rotation should stay relative to the object's origin.