# What is the best way of storing transformations for an object and then applying them with OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, movement, matrix, glm

First some background info...

I have been working on a platformer game, which I draw with OpenGL. The platforms are *cubes* and the player is a *cube*.

The platforms and the player *(both cubes)* are given a position, from which the vertices should be drawn. However, the first cube is at position *[0, 0, 0]* and I would like the player to be on top of this cube. The size of the cubes and player is *[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]* initially.

However, I didn't manage to get the player on *[0, 1, 0]* *(cubes are drawn from their center point I remembered)*, because the scaling didn't seem to work, which led me to believe the method I'm using to store the translations and scaling is inherently bad.

---

I am currently storing the translations and scaling in a matrix, which is part of the object. The object also holds the vertices and the VBO. Let's call it `class Cube`, which thus holds `glm::mat4 m_transform`.

I expose `m_transform` and pass it with `glUniformMatrix4fv(shader.GetUniformLocation("model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(m_transform));`

And at some point I call `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);` to draw the platform/player cube.

So to alter the position of such a cube, I would alter `m_transform`. Such as: `m_transform = glm::translate(m_transform, vec);` where `glm::vec3 vec` is the desired translation to apply.

However, the issues arise when u wish to scale a cube as well, so if we scale with `vec3(0, 2, 0)`, the translations will be twice as large. And I'm unsure where to go from here.

---

I've read that having different matrices for translation, rotation and scaling is the way to go, which I will try, however, I would like to know what the best practices are surrounding this subject.

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this shader, you have to pass a single model matrix, `model`, which is the final object transformation:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(shader.GetUniformLocation("model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(m_transform));
```

But you still can have three different matrices, one for each transformation: translation, rotation and scale, and pass a matrix that is the product of those three transformations.

The thing to remember here is: **order does matter**. Because as you said, if you first **translate** an object, and then **scale** it, the translation shall be scaled, and your object won't be on wanted position.

This is why transformations are generally computed in that order:

```
glm::mat4 translation = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), position); // Translation matrix
glm::mat4 rotation = glm::toMat4(orientation); // Rotation matrix
glm::mat4 scale = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), scaleVector); // Scale matrix

m_transformation = trans * rot * scale; // Final transformation matrix.
```

See this [related answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/29265/68293) for more about transformations order.

Comment: To keep track of the size and position, is it best to simply do `return m_translation[3]` for the position and `return glm::vec3(m_scale[0].x, m_scale[1].y, m_scale[2].z)` for the size or have `glm::vec3 m_position` and update it when translating like so `m_position += position` and when requested, do `return m_position` instead. Or is there perhaps a better way?

Comment: `m_translation` should be the difference between an object's position and world origin. As World origin coordinates are (0, 0, 0), `m_translation` does represent your object's position. So you can return it directly.